# How to save changes made at runtime to an android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, project

I am developing an android application and my app contains a few `ArrayLists` which have some predefined elements when the app is first installed.Now my question is, is it possible to save any changes made to those `ArrayLists` during `runtime`(adding/removing elements) to the project's `source code` when the app closes? I want to use this method (if it's plausible) **for developing purposes only** so don't worry about how other users will behave. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I believe something like [this](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker) should help you.

Comment: what about sharedpreferences?

Comment: use `sharedpreferences` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: @MajidMohammadi , i checked the post and some other similar ones but here's my question: If i use sharedpreferences to add/remove elements from those lists and then write them again using sharedprefs, doesn't that only affect the phone on which the app is currently running on? I mean, it won't add those String,Integers etc. to those ArrayLists so that the changes are present on every application instance right? Please correct me if i'm wrong :D